# How to fix prettier and tslint error with brackets with single props?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint, prettier

I use prettier and tslint, with https://github.com/alexjoverm/tslint-config-prettier and https://github.com/ikatyang/tslint-plugin-prettier .

My `tslint.json` is like

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint-config-airbnb",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rules": {
    "max-line-length": [true, 80],
    "import-name": false,
    "variable-name": false,
    "jsx-boolean-value": false,
    "jsx-no-multiline-js": false,
    "no-else-after-return": false,
    "object-shorthand-properties-first": false,
    "ter-arrow-parens": false,
    "ter-indent": false,
    "prettier": true
  },
  "rulesDirectory": ["tslint-plugin-prettier"]
}
```

And my `.prettierrc` is like

```
{
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

After `tslint --fix "src/**/*.ts"`, codes like below appears:

```
import { getChildrenProceduresSelector } from '@src/entities/procedures/selectors';
```

And the error says `[tslint] Exceeds maximum line length of 80 (max-line-length)` .

But when I fix it manually to

```
import {
  getChildrenProceduresSelector,
} from '@src/entities/procedures/selectors';
```

It says

```
[tslint] Replace `⏎··getChildrenProceduresSelector,⏎` with `·getChildrenProceduresSelector·` (prettier)
```

I use VSCode with tslint and prettier extensions.
My tslint command says the same error.
How to fix this conflicts?

Answer (score 8):

Error in your config comes from `"max-line-length": [true, 80]`. It conflicts with prettier rules. If you want to set `max-line` you should do it in `.prettierc` file -> `"printWidth": 80`.

[tslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/alexjoverm/tslint-config-prettier) - this config disables all the rules from `tslint` that conflicts with `prettier` (So in your case, this plugin disabled `max-line` from `tslint`, but then you set it manually in `rules` section)

[tslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/ikatyang/tslint-plugin-prettier) - this plugin runs prettier rules as `tslint` rules. In addition you need to enable this in `rule` section of your `tslint.json`.

Taking all of that into consideration your configuration should look more or less like this:

```
// With tslint@5.0.0+
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint-config-airbnb",
    "tslint-config-prettier",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier": true
  }
}

// With tslint@5.2.0+
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint-config-airbnb",
    "tslint-config-prettier",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier": true
  },
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "tslint-plugin-prettier"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but it says like this https://github.com/ikatyang/tslint-plugin-prettier#usage , and I use tslint 5.10.0, my configs seem okay.

Comment: So in your environment, does the code like in my question is formatted to new lined?

Comment: I have changed my configs to use `rulesDirectory` and it works fine. So it must be different part of your config that is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for that information. My `tslint-config-prettier-check ./tslint.json` says max-line-length is conflicted, how about yours?

Comment: yes. That is the problem. I ll edit my post for answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178076/discussion-between-kacper-wiszczuk-and-taichi).